# ReactComponent Button value won't render on my react app

Tags: reactjs

I've got a simple React App going on. My `index.js` file looks, of course, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Going deeper, my `App.js` file declares an `App extends Compoennt` class, which contains my to-be-rendered elements and their functions:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./SmartTransit_logo.png";
import MyButton from "./components/MyButton";
import "./App.css";

import { isWallet, helloWorld } from "./services/neo-service";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: ""
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Smart Transit Live Demo</h1>
        </header>

        <div style={{ width: 500, margin: "auto", marginTop: 10 }}>
            <MyButton
                buttonText="My Button"
                onClick={ params => {helloWorld();}}
            />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the declaration of `MyButton` from `/components/MyButton`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class MyButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="MyButton"
      value = {this.props.buttonText}
      >
      {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

MyButton.propTypes = {
    buttonText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default MyButton;
```

Finally, the declaration for `helloWorld()` is done like so (NOTE: `neon-js` is an npm package I'm using):

```
import { wallet } from "@cityofzion/neon-js";

export function isWallet(address) {
  console.log(wallet.isAddress(address));
  return wallet.isAddress(address);
}

export function helloWorld() {
  console.log("Hello world");
  return 1;
}
```

My problem is that the resulting Button doesn't get its `value` text rendered, and although it gets the `CSS` code for it just fine, it appears empty!

[image]

Not only that, but pressing it doesn't log a **"Hello World"** in the console, as it should, so it's even disconnected from its `onClick` function.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Buttons don't receive a "value" prop. The text inside of the button element is what gives it its text.
2. The button does appear to accept children to use as button text, but no children is actually being passed down to it. `this.props.children` is the content between JSX tags when the component is rendered.
3. React doesn't add the event handlers to elements automatically. You have to pass them along yourself in order for them to be properly triggered.

With that in mind, here's how you should render your button in `App`:

```
<MyButton onClick={() => helloWorld()}>
  My Button
</MyButton>
```

And here's how `MyButton`'s code should look:

```
class MyButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="MyButton" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `buttonText` prop is no longer required; that's what the `children` prop is for.

Comment: An explanation, a solution and an optimisation, all in one? Sign me up! Thank you. As I am a newbie, can I ask for a minor explanation on the `onClick = { ()=>helloWorld() }` line? I've declared onClick to be a `required` prop of type `func`, so I'd guess the open-and-closing `{}`s typeset the value ass a `func`. The `()` on the left-hand side, however, is it the equivalent of `no params passed`?

Comment: Sure thing. And to answer your question: yes, you're right, the `()` at the beginning means the function accepts no parameters. Technically the line can be shorter, but I wrote it that way as a way of making sure the `helloWorld()` function gets called with no arguments, for clarity if anything

Comment: Thank you, again. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `super(props)` in class constructor when you are going to use `this.props`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

Define this in `MyButton` component.

Comment: Declaring a `constructor(props)` alongside `render()` did nothing, and additionally threw a warning on the console when starting the react project: `./src/components/MyButton.js
  Line 5:  Useless constructor  no-useless-constructor`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are not calling onClick method from mybutton component and button take it's value between it's opening and closing tag.

Use this code:

this.props.onClick()}> {this.props.buttonText}